# Custom viewgroup is not showing its child custom views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

The draggablepointviews in pathview arent showing up. I did addView in PathView but the pointviews are still not being rendered. Am I missing something? I thought addView was enough and would make the childs render.

PathView.kt

```
class PathView(context: Context) : ViewGroup(context)
{
    private val pointA = DraggablePointView(context)
    private val pointB = DraggablePointView(context)

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        strokeWidth = 15f
        color = Color.WHITE
    }

    init
    {
        pointA.x = 50f
        pointA.y = 50f
        pointB.x = 330f
        pointB.y = 330f
        addView(pointA, 100, 100)
        addView(pointB, 100, 100)
        setWillNotDraw(false)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?)
    {
        if (canvas == null)
            return

        // Draw a line between pointA and pointB
        canvas.drawLine(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointB.x, pointB.y, paint)
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int)
    {
    }
}
```

DraggablePointView.kt

```
class DraggablePointView(context: Context) : ImageView(context)
{
    init
    {
        setImageResource(R.drawable.point)
        setWillNotDraw(false)
    }

    override fun onDragEvent(event: DragEvent?): Boolean
    {
        println("DRAG EVENT")
        if (event == null)
            return false
        x = event.x
        y = event.y
        return true
    }
}
```

Then:

```
val pathView = PathView(context)
frameLayout.addView(pathView)
```

Comment: Unrelated: `canvas: Canvas` is never null, there would be no point in invoking `onDraw` with no canvas, right? `event: DragEvent` is also non-nullable for the same reason. Define nullable types where it makes sense.

Comment: I thought whether a parameter was nullable was controlled by the android framework and that I had no control over it.

Comment: Android can't often tell you if a type is nullable (see [platform types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))). Sometimes even nullability of function return value depends on parameters. It's our responsibility to decide when a nullable type makes sense. In this case, if canvas was ever null, something went terribly wrong, and it should crash.

Answer (score 0):

### 1) Draw the line

To force a view to draw, call [`invalidate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()).

#### void invalidate()

> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` will be called at some point in the future.

#### void invalidate (int l, int t, int r, int b)

> Mark the area defined by the rect (l, t, r, b) as needing to be drawn. The coordinates of the dirty rect are relative to the view. If the view is visible, `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` will be called at some point in the future.

### 2) Draw the points

Since you extend `ViewGroup` you're responsible for measuring and laying out the child views.

Perhaps you should extend `AbsoluteLayout` instead, which already has the measurement and layout logic programmed. Then you can set the coordinates like so:

```
val lp = layoutParams as AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams
lp.x = event.x
lp.y = event.y
requestLayout()
```

Or perhaps you should extend `View` and draw the points in the same fashion as the line. That should be most efficient. You don't need child views to draw, you need just canvas.

- Override [`onTouchEvent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) to listen for and react to touch.
- Draw the drawable to canvas by calling `setBounds` (tell it where to draw) and `draw`.

Comment: 1. Drawing the line already works
2. Why should I use ontouchevent when I already use ondragevent?
3. does calling setBounds(0,0,0,0) mean that it will take the whole canvas?

Comment: Also, why would I need to "layout and measure the child views" while only thing I do is setting the x and y values of the childs. I dont need to measure more.

Comment: 2. `onDragEvent` seems like a high level interface. 3. `setBounds(0,0,0,0)` means "draw from [0,0] to [0,0]". It wouldn't draw anything. [Read the third paragraph here for instructions.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html)

Comment: So you set some x and y values in your DraggablePointView. And what? Who reads those values? What happens? Nothing. On top of that you extended `ViewGroup`. That's the common parent of all layouts. And the class is quite stupid, it supports child views, but it has no other logic in it. It doesn't know how to measure the children or where to put them. `PathView` has two children but it doesn't measure them, lay them out, draw them. It doesn't know how.